# Where can I find documentation on the format of v2 Git pack index files?

Tags: php, git

I'm working on a simple PHP read-only implementation of Git and I've got it mostly working, but I can't figure out what the exact format is of Git pack index files (version 2). All documentation I have found so far is either vague and only focused towards interpreting them with Git itself, or only applies to version 1 which is, from my understanding, considerably different. Using an existing Git implementation for PHP is not an option (I've tried a few, and keep hitting issues with them).

I'm basically in need of some simple and generic documentation about the format of a v2 pack index file, nothing PHP-specific. Where can I find this?

Comment: The file format - both reading and writing - should be at least documented within the source-code of GIT itself - which is freely available for studying it.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: @wwarren I did, actually, but I haven't gotten around to finishing the entire implementation, although most of it is done. Progress so far is at http://git.cryto.net/cgit/crytoteam/tree/public_html/libgit?id=6480a4b0bba5e3666a3ec3f7dceff08f539e8be2

Comment: Thanks - be sure to keep an eye on updates, I plan on continuing work on that particular project soon.

Comment: @SvenSlootweg I'm working on the ability to accept push/pull/fetch/upload requests in pure PHP and it's almost working. The bit I had to cheat on (call the git executable) is the bit that builds the packfiles for downloading during a clone, pull or fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation included with the Git sources](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt) seems to have a reasonably complete description of the v1 and v2 packfile formats.

And of course there are a variety of other software implements that understand this format, including [dulwich](https://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/) for Python and of course [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) for C.  Studying these may help out your understanding if the technical documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone seems to give link #1 below as the definitive documentation on the git packfile format. I found it to be pretty sparse and I didn't understand it very well. It took a lot of digging but I eventually found link #2. It was much more comprehensive and easier to understand. I don't see how I could possibly implement the format with the docs in link #1. I think I could possibly do it with link #2.

I hope you are successful it would be good to have a more complete pure-php git implementation than the one's that currently exist.

1. http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt;h=1803e64e465fa4f8f0fe520fc0fd95d0c9def5bd;hb=HEAD
2. http://home.cofares.net/GIT/book/7_the_packfile.html

Answer (score 0):

The Git packfile format is not particularly easy to deal with - it's probably far easier to manipulate it via libgit2 instead of reading it directly - check out [php-libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git).